# How can I hide indent guides in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I hide the following lines to get a cleaner code view?

[image]

Like this in the official documentation:

[image]

How can I do that or find settings in the documentation?

Comment: you want to collapse that lines ???

Comment: just hide. I want to get more clean code view. Like this view in official documentation (http://prntscr.com/iqkmtz)

Comment: See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings, then look for `Fold (collapse)`

Comment: Sorry for my language. I mean indent guides.

Comment: check the answer :) updated

Answer (score 59):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>, type `settings` and select `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` to open **User Settings**, and add this:

> ```
> // Controls whether the editor should render indent guides
>   "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
> ```

This will disable the indent guides.

See the [documentation for User Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

**Edit:** as on 30th May, 2022, this setting is called

```
  "editor.guides.indentation": false,
```

Comment: You can also reach this file navigating to **File -> Preferences - > Settings** as Sajeetharan mentioned in his answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer just so it's according to the real problem faced by OP.

Comment: `editor.renderIndentGuides` has been deprecated in favor of `editor.guides.indentation` in [version 1.6.1](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61).

Comment: @Darren - very useful information, though it's version 1.61 (not 1.6.1). While the deprecated setting does still work (as of 1.67), it is no longer documented (so if you follow the link in the answer, you won't find it) and, even more importantly, it doesn't work in the per-language settings (but the new setting does).

Answer (score 20):

I tried the previous answers, but it would not let me, as it said the file was read-only, so the solution I found was below:

Click on menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*.

In the search box, type "render indent guides" (without the `""`)

*Untick* the box which says *"Controls whether the editor should render indent guides"*.

[image]

This removes the indent guides.

Comment: this is the real answer... code folding + no indent lines.

Comment: If you also want to get rid of dots which appear after "deselecting render indent guides", change the "Render Whitespaces" setting to none.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a way to hide the indent lines but keep the active line indicator.

Add this to `settings.json`.

```js
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorIndentGuide.background": "#00000000" // hide via 100% transparency.
}
```

Only the active indent block will be visible.
[image: only active guide showing]

To control the color of the active line, add...

```js
"editorIndentGuide.activeBackground": "#444444b9" // Grey with some transparency.
```

Comment: super helpful. Thanks.

Comment: This is super neat. Thank you!

Comment: I like it. Slightly out-of-the-box approach that doesn't do *exactly* what was asked for (even after clarification), but might be even better, depending on your tastes.

Answer (score 10):

**Method-1  (using settings.json)**

`"editor.renderIndentGuides": false,` is now **deprecated** in vs code.

Use  `"editor.guides.indentation": false` instead.

[image]

---

**Method-2  (using settings UI)**

Goto settings > search `editor.guides.indentation`  > Remove 'tip' mark for guides indentation.

[image]

Comment: We should really vote this answer up so that it becomes the top answer. Besides simply being newer and not deprecated, `editor.guides.indentation` can be used as a per-language setting, while the deprecated one can't.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*

And search for **`"editor.folding"`**. Set it to

**`"editor.folding": false`**

This will disable the lines and the folding function.

Since you want to disable the render indent guides,

From the **[documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)**

```
  "editor.renderIndentGuides": false,
```

This will disable the indent guides.

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED:
"editor.renderIndentGuides": false

Comment: Ohh, you said code folding, so I tought you meant the collapse buttons.

Comment: dude your question and answer are totally different

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry for my language.

Comment: Please consider accepting [@Begula's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70419102/95852) so that it gets the checkmark and is listed above answers that are now obsolete.