# Hide bracket lines in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've tried the solutions in

[How can I hide indent guides in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49255934/how-can-i-hide-indent-guides-in-visual-studio-code)

but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

I think my issue is with bracket lines, not indent:
[image]

Comment: Those are coming from one of your extensions, not from anything built-in to vscode.

Comment: Can you check if you have the bracket pair colorizer extension added?

Answer (score 0):

this was caused by bracket pair colorizer 2 extension