# How to set the display and color of such vertical lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to set the display and color of such vertical lines in a JSON settings file of VS Code theme?
I'd like to be able to turn them on and off in different themes, as well as change the color of these lines.
[the lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyEe0.png)

Chat GPT hasn't helped me...

Comment: dual duplicate. easy google as long as you know the right words. "vscode change color of indent guides" -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/47942390/11107541. "vscode disable indent guides" -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/49255934/11107541

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change indent guide line color between brackets in VSCODE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942390/how-to-change-indent-guide-line-color-between-brackets-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oderwat.indent-rainbow) VS-Code extension. It offers coloful inted lines (and spacing). However, I am not sure about en-/disabling them on specific themes - languages should be possible tough!

Comment: Thank u, sir! )